# Change the StatusBar text color based on underlying content

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, statusbar

In our application we have a page where the StatusBar overlays user generated images. Sometimes these images have a darker top, and sometimes a lighter. This means sometimes the Statusbar on that page isn't visible, or is extremely hard to see. Considering this is the main page of our application, I'm wondering if there's a way to change the color of the StatusBar text based on the underlying content.

(Best font color for the background).

Yes, I'm aware we could show a static background color for the StatusBar, but that would be extremely tacky.

Comment: I am afraid, there is not such a solution, that would work for all the underlaying images. Suppose, your image goes from the black on left to the white on the right. Definitely it is not possible to have multicolor statusbar.

Comment: @pedrouan - That is a very great point which I didn't think about. I guess I'll just put a `rgba(0,0,0,0.3)` overlay on the images so that statusbar can always be seen.

Comment: That's a good idea. Maybe you find the best white/black intensity so it always be visible and universal as well. Or to make blurred background so the visibility would be a bit better. I saw some solutions where all the status bar is disappearing while on the image. After scrolling when a bar is on text, it appears back.

Answer (score 1):

I have perfect way for this: in top of your view with image create minimal shadow. It will be invisible to the user

Comment: This is a great idea, doesn't answer the question, but still a good idea as a workaround.